# Java Http GET request insanely slow compared to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, get, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I was testing some Http GET requests with Java and JavaScript when I noticed the Java implementation performed consistently much worse than the JavaScript (node.js) app. My 2 simple implementations are as follows:

Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            sendGetRequest();
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;
            System.out.println(duration + "ms");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void sendGetRequest() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/80.0.3987.95 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        con.setUseCaches(false);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        con.disconnect();
        System.out.println(responseCode);
    }
}
```

Notice how I'm not even getting the json, I'm just getting the response code. This request takes 2800ms on average. (You can see how I calculate the duration in my main method)

Now here's my node.js code which takes about 75ms on average to read the json data:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.time('p1')
fetch('https://localhost:8000/test.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/80.0.3987.95 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'DNT': 1,
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'TE': 'Trailers'
    },
    body: null
}).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json))

console.timeEnd('p1')
```

Again you can see how I calculate the time passed. I was surprised by the results as my teachers used to tell me Java should be orders of magnitude faster than JavaScript. Is this just one of the strenghts of JS / node.js? Or am I doing something very wrong in my Java implementation?

Comment: Your `fetch()` call returns **immediately**.

Comment: Put your `.timeEnd()` inside the last `.then()` callback.

Comment: also in 2020 Java is not "orders of magnitude" faster than JavaScript.

Comment: I put the `.timeEnd()` inside the last `.then()` callback and it actually seems to shave off an additional 10ms, is that normal?

Comment: Is there any way to make somethin in Java that returns immediately as well? This experiment is me trying to figure out the fastest way to retrieve this json info with either Java or JS

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I'm actually looking into that already and there seems to be a lot of info available online :)